# rmongodb: $in-query doesn't work

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

The items of the collection of the Mongo database I'm working with have got a field "UID". I'd like to look for all items with UID equals 1, 2 or 5.

Here's the MongoVUE-query:

```
{"UID":{"$in":[1, 2, 5]}}
```

This works.

Here is the query in `rmongodb`:

```
cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, ns,
                     query = list(UID = list('$in' = c(1,2,5))))
dummy <- mongo.cursor.next(cursor)
db.value <- mongo.cursor.value(cursor)
db.value
# NULL
```

Another try:

```
  cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, ns,
                   query = '{"UID":{"$in":[1,2,5]}}')
```

Same result. However, if I try this to fetch just one item:

```
  cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, ns,
                   query = list(UID = 1))
```

it works.

Any idea what's going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I figured out that the following indeed does work:

```
cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, ns,
                     query = list(UID = list('$in' = c(1,2,5))))
```

but only if the vector has more than one element. I was using a one-element-vector for testing purposes (`c(1)`) which failed. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if for some reason it's the expected behaviour.

The JSON-query still doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the result of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252          LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] mixtools_1.0.1    segmented_0.3-1.0 MASS_7.3-32       boot_1.3-11       plyr_1.8.1        reshape2_1.4      data.table_1.9.4 
 [8] stringr_0.6.2     ggplot2_0.9.3.1   XML_3.98-1.1      rmongodb_1.6.5   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] chron_2.3-45     colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.0.3       gtable_0.1.2     jsonlite_0.9.7   munsell_0.4.2   
 [8] proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.1      scales_0.2.4     tools_3.0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer** - R's **unnamed lists are converted into MongoDB arrays**. So in case your query looks like `{id : {$in : [17]}}`, your R's bson constructor should be `mongo.bson.from.list(list(id = list("$in" = list(17))))`

**Long answer**
 1. First of all, please, use `mongo.bson.from.list`, it is much more efficient and more straighforward then `mongo.bson.from.JSON`, which use it internally. `mongo.bson.from.list` directly converts R types into MongoDB types.
2. Try to evaluate this expression in R:

```
c(1) == 1
class(1)
class(c(1))
```

There is no diffrence between scalars and vectors, so we can't predict what you mean when you write `c(1)` or `1`. But when we evaluate `c(1,2)`, of course we understand, that user use array and R's array will be converted into MongoDB's array. So we use R's `list` type to explicitly point when we need array.
3. Be careful with implicit type coercion:

```
print(mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"UID" : {"$in" : [1, 2, 5]}}'))
print(mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"UID" : {"$in" : [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}}'))
print(mongo.bson.from.list(list("UID" = list('$in' = c(1,2,5))))
class(c(1,2,3))
# [1] "numeric"
class(c(1L,2L,3L))
# [1] "integer"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried `mongo.find(mongo, ns, query = list("UID" = list('$in' = list(1,2,5))))`, but this didn't work (pointer is `nil`). However, it still works with `c(1,2,5)`. From what you said, I would have expected that `print(mongo.bson.from.list(list("UID" = list('$in' = list(1,2,5)))))` should yield the same result as `print(mongo.bson.from.list(list("UID" = list('$in' = c(1,2,5)))))`, but in reality the BSON looks a bit differently: the type of `$in` is 3 (bsonOBJECT) with `list(1,2,5)` and 4 (bsonARRAY) with `c(1,2,5)`.

Comment: what version of rmongodb do you use? can you provide `sessionInfo()` information? it looks very strange, because on my computer both have type 4.

Comment: I've added the output of `sessionInfo()` to the original post. You're right, I'm not using the latest version. If you think that's the reason, I'd update and try it again.

Comment: please, update package to latest version. This is defenitely the reason of this type of issues. There are many improvements and bug fixes in it. Starting from 1.8.0 in most cases rmongodb works as user expects.